# SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2)

Tags: networking, server, sql

I have a problem in which I can not find a solution and I was hoping that you could help me out.
I rolled back my server and now none of the php scripts can now connect to other servers. The scripts are up to date as the rollback is from last week.

I get the SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2)

And on cmd I get:

> SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0 Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expire
>   d SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 10022 Error =
>   [unixODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related
>   or                                              instance-specific
>   error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Ser
>   ver. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is
>   correct an                                             d if SQL Server
>   is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
>   see SQL Server Books Online. SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 10022
>   Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP
>   Provider: Error                                              code
>   0x2726

On telnet I can connect to remote server. 
sqlcmd also lets me connect to the remote server

Please if anyone could help me out. I do not know what to do next.
All help will be greatly appreciated.

This is a test script to try the connection

```
$link = mssql_connect('xx.xxx.xxxx.xx,1433','myuname','mypwd');

    if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL:'. mssql_get_last_message());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to modify the etc/network and modify interfaces file and do
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` For some reason the dns-namesevers were wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The fix for me was with three steps:

First, I edited `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` and changed the tds version like this:

```
tds version = 8.0
```

The second step was not entering port number. The port was already 1433, and not specifying it fixed the exact same issue on my case.

Lastly, to connect properly, I had to restart networking as @user1054844 [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/525549/107722) as this:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

After all these steps, I was able to connect and work with the SQL Server database.