# UBUNTU/PHP: Can not connect to sql server 2008

Tags: server, php, connection, sql

We took a copy of our Ubuntu virtual server and changed its name and IP. In every other way it is a duplicate of our production server. Now for some reason we can't get php connection to SQL-SERVER. So I was hoping someone here could help me out what to do next.

Thanks for your help!

PHPINFO()

```
MSSQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Library version     FreeTDS

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mssql.allow_persistent  On  On
mssql.batchsize 0   0
mssql.charset   no value    no value
mssql.compatability_mode    Off Off
mssql.connect_timeout   5   5
mssql.datetimeconvert   On  On
mssql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_procs Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.min_error_severity    10  10
mssql.min_message_severity  10  10
mssql.secure_connection Off Off
mssql.textlimit Server default  Server default
mssql.textsize  Server default  Server default
mssql.timeout   60  60
```

Connector gives me nothing but "MSSQL error:"

```
    $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
    if (!$dbhandle) {

die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

NOTE! I do not get any error nro or msg on the die command

UPDATE:
Also tried this, but no help
[SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525530/sqlstatehy000-unknown-host-machine-name-severity-2/587656#587656)

UPDATE 2:
-Reinstalled according to https://zxtech.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-ubuntu/
-Ping: OK
-Telnet: OK 
-Still no error msg on php scripts

UPDATE 3
Found the problem: Server name is not working. As I have connected on sqlservename.sql.something now I have to connect with the straight up ip 123.4567.890.12

Comment: Did you change the value for your `$myServer` variable when you migrated the server?

Comment: We changed it to apache-sites-enabled script after migration

Comment: since we do not have enough information to analyse it, I guess: Your test machine cannot connect to mssql server, because of a firewall? Maybe you are using an mssql srver with only one allowed connection at a time (I really do not know nor care under what conditions you are allowed to use m$ precious databaseserver)?

Comment: Firewall rules have been dublicated to allow the copied server, and  it allows multiple connections. No need to be hostile @mondjunge I´am only trying to ask where to look next

Comment: Also if it was that firewall is blocking the connection there should be "Connection refused" given as error

Comment: ok, can you check somehow, if any requests reaches the mssql server? Tried to ping the mssql server from the test-vm? In PHP Manual(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php#105132), somebody pointed out, that SELinux could prevend Apache from connecting to network. You said it gives you "MSSQL error:", but what number behind the colon? Normally there should be a Number you can google.

Comment: We bought up another dublicate without reinstallation and it works also with IP (and did not even have to reinstall anything). Any ideas what could cause the freetds to "lose" the servername?

Answer (score 1):

Finally we found out the reason: The problem was that on migration the file containing our DNS-SERVERS was overwritten by Wmvare. Meaning that even though the servers were duplicates the IP for our DNS-servers was changed..

We had no reason to suspect this as it should have been full copy of functioning server